# Php + mysql, slot switching

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, so im in the middle of making a pokemon web based rpg, and its been going alright except ow im stumped at the part where I need to switch the pokemon that are stored in slot (0) = your box to slot 1 on your team. I have figured it out so that it will switch the pokemon stored in slot 0 to slot 1 on your team but it only works with the first one in the list of slot 0 ( there are multiple with slot set to 0 ) I hope im making sense I need it so that I can click submit under any of the pokemon in your box and it will send that one to slot 1
Here is my code so far:

```
 <?php
include 'core/database/connect.php';
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
?>

<div id="middle">
<div class="post">
<div class="postheader">
<h1>Your Box</h1>
</div>
<div class="postcontent">
<p>
<center>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['slot1'])) {

session_start();


// here we grab the pokemon in slot 1 
$sql66 = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE
belongsto='".$_SESSION['username']."'
AND (slot='1')";
$result66 = mysql_query($sql66) or die(mysql_error());
$poke66 = mysql_fetch_array($result66);


$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE
belongsto='".$_SESSION['username']."'
AND (slot='0')";
$result55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die(mysql_error());
$poke55 = mysql_fetch_array($result55);


$_SESSION['idpoke5'] = $poke55['id'] ;

$_SESSION['idpoke6'] = $poke66['id'] ;

if(mysql_num_rows($result66)==0){
echo "no pokemon in slot 6 so we will drag the pokemon from slot 5 into slot 6 ";

} else {
$result666 = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET slot=slot-1 WHERE id =  '{$_SESSION['idpoke6']}'")
or die(mysql_error());
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;


}

if(mysql_num_rows($result55)==0){
echo "no pokemon in slot 5";

} else {

$result5done = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET slot=slot+1 WHERE id =  '{$_SESSION['idpoke5']}'")
or die(mysql_error());
}

?>

<?php

 echo "Your pokemon has been moved";
 }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='".  $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

echo '<img src="pokemon/'.$row['type'] .''.$battle_get2['pic'].'" border=0><p></p>
</a>' ; 
echo $row['pokemon'];
?>
<p></p>
<?php
echo "Level:";
echo $row ['level'];
?>
<p><form name="slot1" action="" method="post">
<div align="center">
<input type="submit" value="slot1" name="slot1">
</div>
</form> </p>
<?php
echo "Gender:";
echo $row['gender'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
</center>
</p>
</div>
<div class="postfooter"></div>
</div>
```

I know im not very good at explaining it, but some help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I was told to use `session_start()` at the ABSOLUTE first line of php, I'm not sure if it will cause issues but I see yours is a wee bit down

Comment: As long as it's used before emitting any content or using any other session functions or `$_SESSION` itself, it'll work fine.  Having it here after things have been emitted will probably break unless output buffering is enabled.